# Jenkins view is getting duplicate every container restart

Tags: jenkins

I'm using Jenkins container and facing an issue that each container restart, the RunningJobs getting duplicate:
[image: Jenkins]

Any idea what is the root cause and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to remove the directory `init.groovy.d` from Jenkins home folder (inside the container)